# Whats wrong with my perl substitution?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a directory of files I am trying to split down into subdirectories using perl due to the quantity of files. The filenames are formatted with dates at the start in the form YYYYMMDD and I'm trying to split on that. I am using the following code adapted from [this StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242662/linux-move-1-million-files-into-prefix-based-created-folders):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

opendir DIR, "." or die "opendir: $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;
foreach my $f (@files) {
    -f $f or next;
    (my $new_name = $f) =~ s!^((....)(..)(..).*)$!$2/$3/$4/$1/;
    -e $new_name and die "$new_name already exists";
    rename($f, $new_name);
}
```

However I get a 'Substitution replacement not terminated at movefiles.pl line 10.' when I try and run this code. As far as I can see I am escaping and terminating the substitution correctly?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you ought to check if rename was successful.

Comment: Good point! I'll fix that up too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `!` as a regular expression delimiter. You have one to start it, one to separate the match part from the replace part, but don't have one at the end.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I knew it was something obvious but I missed that.