# Linux: Update directory structure for millions of images which are already in prefix-based folders

Tags: linux, bash, directory

This is basically a follow-up to [Linux: Move 1 million files into prefix-based created Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242662/linux-move-1-million-files-into-prefix-based-created-folders)

The original question:

> I want to write a shell command to rename all of those images into the
>   following format:
>
> original: filename.jpg new: /f/i/l/filename.jpg

Now, I want to take all of those files and add an additional level to the directory structure, e.g:

> original: `/f/i/l/filename.jpg` new: `/f/i/l/e/filename.jpg`

Is this possible to do with command line or bash?

Comment: Which part of your original question are you having trouble with? It's essentially the same concept.

Comment: Looping through the existing directory structure without entering the newly created folders

Comment: Why loop at all? `cd f/i/l ; mkdir e ; cp * e ; rm *` should do what you want... ( you should change the last `rm` to `echo` to test it first ) ...

Comment: Because there are about 36*36*36 folders in total: 0/0/0, 0/0/1, 0/0/2, /0/0/3, etc.

Comment: I guess that I'm not understanding what exactly you are trying to do other than move files into a sub-directory...

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, for ~46,000 directories. Your suggestion would help me handle 1 of them.

Comment: Your question shows a file being moved, not a directory; would all the directories be the same name? It's unclear what you mean. The command shown would move files ( not directories ) from f/i/l to f/i/l/e.

Comment: Originally, I had millions of images in one directory. Then, I used the command from the original question to move them all into prefix-based directories. So there are millions of images spread across many directories in a filename-based structure, 3 levels deep. I want to update this structure to 4 levels deep, using the same naming convention.

Comment: How is the name of the 4th directory supposed to be obtained though? You've left out this seemingly important detail.

Comment: It's the 4th character of the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to simply loop over all the directories you already have, and in each bottom-level subdirectory create the new subdirectory and move the files:

```
for d in ?/?/?/; do (
  cd "$d" &&
  printf '%.4s\0' * | uniq -z | 
  xargs -0 bash -c 'for prefix do
                      s=${prefix:3:1}
                      mkdir -p "$s" && mv "$prefix"* "$s"
                    done' _
) done
```

That probably needs a bit of explanation.

The glob `?/?/?/` matches all directory paths made up of three single-character subdirectories. Because it ends with a `/`, everything it matches is a directory so there is no need to test.

```
( cd "$d" && ...; )
```

executes `...` after cd'ing to the appropriate subdirectory. Putting that block inside `( )` causes it to be executed in a subshell, which means the scope of the `cd` will be restricted to the parenthesized block. That's easier and safer than putting `cd ..` at the end.

We then collecting the subdirectories first, by finding the unique initial strings of the files:

```
printf '%.4s\0' * | uniq -z | xargs -0 ...
```

That extracts the first four letters of each filename, nul-terminating each one, then passes this list to `uniq` to eliminate duplicates, providing the `-z` option because the input is nul-terminated, and then passes the list of unique prefixes to `xargs`, again using `-0` to indicate that the list is nul-terminated. `xargs` executes a command with a list of arguments, issuing the command several times only if necessary to avoid exceeding the command-line limit. (We probably could have avoided the use of `xargs` but it doesn't cost that much and it's a lot safer.)

The command called with xargs is bash itself; we use the `-c` option to pass it a command to be executed. That command iterates over its arguments by using the `for arg in` syntax. Each argument is a unique prefix; we extract the fourth character from the prefix to construct the new subdirectory and then `mv` all files whose names start with the prefix into the newly created directory.

The `_` at the end of the `xargs` invocation will be passed to `bash` (as with all the rest of the arguments); `bash -c` uses the first argument following the command as the `$0` argument to the script, which is not part of the command line arguments iterated over by the `for arg in` syntax. So putting the `_` there means that the argument list constructed by `xargs` will be precisely `$1`, `$2`, ... in the execution of the bash command.

Comment: Bloody brilliant, thanks. It took me a while to understand the underscore thing. I'm a little confused about exactly how the arguments are getting passed by xargs. How is 'prefix' getting assigned?

Comment: @dan: `for var in` is a special form of the `for` statement which iterates over the command's arguments ($1, $2, ...). `xargs` takes a list of arguments from its stdin and applies them to the command supplied as its arguments. Here, "applies" simply means that it repeatedly puts as many as it can at the end of the command until it has used them all.

Comment: Ah, okay. So the underscore is being passed to the inline command as $0 which does not get iterated by the for loop.

Comment: @dan: precisely. `xargs bash -c '...' _` is a standard usage pattern.

Comment: Made one update: added a `test "$s" && ` before `mkdir` in case the folder was empty. Also, I ran this on the folder with millions of images and it was indeed much, much faster than the solution I came up with!

Comment: @dan: Oops, I missed the `-p` option. I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've created a very crude solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file1 in *; do
    if [[ -d "$file1" ]]; then
        cd "$file1"
        for file2 in *; do
            if [[ -d "$file2" ]]; then
                cd "$file2"
                for file3 in *; do
                    if [[ -d "$file3" ]]; then
                        cd "$file3"
                        for file4 in *; do
                            if [[ -f "$file4" ]]; then
                                echo "mkdir -p ${file4:3:1}/; mv $file4 ${file4:3:1}/;"
                                mkdir -p ${file4:3:1}/; mv $file4 ${file4:3:1}/;
                            fi
                        done
                        cd ..
                    fi
                done
                cd ..
            fi
        done
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

I should warn that this is untested, as my actual structure varies slightly, but I wanted to keep the question/answer consistent with the original question for clarity.

That being said, I'm sure a much more elegant solution exists than this one.

Comment: That's not an unreasonable solution, particularly if you only want to do it once. I provided a slightly shorter and probably faster version, but I don't know if you will find it more "elegant".